# Cant find app location

Tags: 14.04, tuxpaint

I installed A app called Tuxpaint But when I looked for it I could not find it. I know it installed because on the Lubuntu Software Center It showed up on installed Packages. Because I can't find the location I can not use the app.

Comment: Try `/usr/share/applications`. Also look under `/opt/`.

Comment: use the command: $`which tuxpaint`   pls note tuxpaint also has a config-directory, and file septate from the app installation directory.

Comment: also you can try with `whereis tuxpaint`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the command in the terminal find for searching an folder:

```
find / -name tuxpaint
```

or you can be more accurate in your research by specify an repertory

```
find /usr/ -name tuxpaint
```

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and run any of these commands to find the location (path):

```
find `pwd` -name "filename"
```

`readlink -f "filename "`

`whereis "filename"`

`which "filename"`

`sudo find "$(cd ..; pwd)" -name "filename"`

`sudo find .. -name "filename" -exec readlink -f {} \;`

("file name"=tuxpaint)