# Android studio is installed however I'm unable to locate or open it

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu-for-android

I have installed `android studio` using the instructions on the following site:

[Android studio for ubuntu](https://paolorotolo.github.io/android-studio/)

Now once the install was complete I can see it was successful from the following:

[image]

However, no matter what I try I simply cannot find nor open it.

I've attempted:

```
android-studio
android
```

Ive tried searching for it on my computer but without results.

Has anyone ever tried the same and know what is going on?

Comment: refer answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/671926/cant-find-app-location/672022#672022)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the guide you've linked to it claims that android-studio will be installed at `/opt/android-studio`, try typing the following into a terminal to check whether it's there:

```
ls -lh /opt/
```

Or otherwise use your file manager GUI to have a look.

Answer (score 5):

1. Check in the `/opt` folder if you have the directory `android-studio`.

   On terminal:

   ```
     cd /opt
     ls
   ```
2. If you find the directory `android-studio`, change the directory to
         cd /android-studio/bin
3. You will find various files there. Run the studio.sh file

   ```
     sh studio.sh
   ```
4. You will get the installation wizard.

   Edit:
5. To open android studio, locate the path where Android Studio is installed. Use

   ```
   cd ~/installed-path/android-studio/bin
   ```

   Open studio with the command

   ```
   ./studio.sh
   ```

Answer (score 5):

For me the path was:

`/snap/android-studio/current/android-studio/bin`

I'm on Ubuntu 20.4.3 LTS.

Answer (score 4):

Look in `/usr/local/`.

That's where my Android Studio was residing, **`/usr/local/android-studio`**.